# Using partition to install Ubuntu Server rather than entire disk

Tags: dual-boot, server, partitioning

I'm a newbie to Ubuntu Server and I would like to host a website with it.
I want to use Dual Booting with Windows 10, installing Ubuntu Server 18.04 from a Flash drive, I started from it, selected language, keyboard layout etc. and then it asked me where to install it, and I can only select the whole drive to install, but the thing is that I use that drive for windows 10 and disk D, and I want just to use a part of that drive like 100 GB, not the whole of it.
Is it possible?

Comment: You understand that when you boot Windows, your website will be down. If you are not yet ready to get rid of Windows, a better solution may be to create a virtual machine inside Windows, and run the Ubuntu server in the VM.

Comment: There are many guides ...:https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-install-ubuntu-server#0

Comment: You probably need to repartition your drive to create a partition for Ubuntu.to dual boot. Please post information on how your drive(s) are partitioned.